# Difference in behavior between onkeydown and onkeyup

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Wondering if anyone might be able to help me with the differences between keyup and keydown and why they don't work the same way?

I have a jsfiddle here where I was doing some examples
https://jsfiddle.net/m9wcn982/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="exercise">
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-on:keyup="listen">
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-on:keydown="listen">
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#exercise',
    data: {
        value: ''
    },
    methods: {
      listen: function(){
        this.value = event.target.value;
      }
    }
});
```

Why does keydown lag 1 character behind while keyup always outputs what key was input immediately after depressing it for example, i'll type "foo" into the 2nd box, but only get "fo" as a value.  But if I type "foo" into the first box I get "foo" as the value.

Comment: The input box value doesn't doesn't change immediately on `keydown`, If you log out `event.key`, though, you can capture the key that that was pressed. You're setting `this.value` to the value of the input, which isn't updated yet when `keydown` fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keydown` is when the key is first depressed. The value of the element hasn't changed yet. It's a way that you can cancel changing the value.

`keyup` is when it's released and in between the 2 the value of the element has changed.

Comment: I've seen this answer several times while trying to search for the answer to this, but why is it that this only matters for something like this.  But if you change it to an alert when you keydown, it functions the same as keyup.

Comment: @Hudspeth because theres a `keyup` in there.

Comment: That's what I am trying to wrap my head around.  To me it makes sense that if I have something hooked up to keydown to set the value of something, then it would set that as soon as the key is pressed down.  But the behavior isn't what I expect, only keyup has that behavior.  Maybe I am just reading to much into it.

Comment: @Hudspeth like i stated, `keydown` is a hook to do some cancelling.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks.  It makes sense otherwise what would be the difference between the two if they didn't have some sort of differentiating features.

Comment: @Hudspeth - Consider this: you want to disable auto-repeat when a key is held down. On the `keydown` event you set a flag, then ignore (cancel) all further keydown events for that key until you see a corresponding `keyup` event and clear the flag.  Pressing and releasing the `a` key will cause a keydown/keyup pair, but pressing and holding `a` will generate  a whole lot of keydowns with a single keyup.

Answer (score 0):

The keydown and keyup events fire when the user presses a key.

`keydown`: Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

`keyup`: Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.